# Why is the <p> element green?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was looking at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:not) CSS example from the Mozilla page for the `:not()` selector.

The example is:

```css
p:not(.classy) { color: red; }
:not(p) { color: green; }
```

```html
<p>Irgendein Text.</p>
<p class="classy">Irgendein anderer Text.</p>
<span>Noch mehr Text<span>
```

What I totally understand:

- I get why the first `p` element is red, it's because it is a `p` element and it does not have the class 'classy'.
- I also get why the `span` element is green, it's because it's selected by the `:not(p)`, it is not a `p` element

But why is the second `p` element green? It would not be selected by the first selector, because it is a `p` element without the class `classy`. But it would not be selected by the second one, because it is a `p` element. So why is it green?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The second `p` isn't `:not(.classy)` so it **isn't** `color: red`. This means it still has its *default* colour, which is `color: inherit`.

The `body` element is `:not(p)` so it is `color: green`.

The second `p` therefore inherits the green colour from the `body` element.

The developer tools in your browser would have told you this:

[image: Developer tools showing CSS rules applied to the second paragraph as described above]

Comment: I should add that anyone that's about to claim that :not() "requires" a type or class selector to work is wrong, because as shown :not() does work unqualified - the results just become counter-intuitive due to other factors at play, such as inheritance in this case. Not everything boils down to just the selector matching the element in question, because the selector may very well be matching other elements and applying styles that affect the layout of the element in question.

Comment: I was playing with `:not([required])` as quick polyfill for `:optional`, but quickly found out that it was not what I had in mind.

Comment: I don't think the person asking the question is at the stage where they know about "developer tools" yet — perhaps you could also include a summary of how they can be accessed.

Answer (score 4):

In Addition to @Quentin answer, for your understand try to add your elements under one parent and apply the CSS with parent selector reference. Now you will get exactly what you expected. Look at the below snippet.

```css
.test p:not(.classy) { color: red; }
.test :not(p) { color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>Irgendein Text.</p>
  <p class="classy">Irgendein anderer Text.</p>
  <span>Noch mehr Text</span>
</div>
```

So in your case the parent element is `body` and inherited the color from there like the above answer.